# css flex-box multiple overflow scroll

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox, overflow

I wonder if it possible to use flex in order to set the width of an overflow-scrolled row to the width of a sibling non overflow-scrolled row.

See this example: https://codepen.io/AgentCisco/pen/mdKeaRQ

css:

```
body {
  background: #aaa;
}

// outer parent to cut a viewing window
#container {
  // center in parent
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  background: #444;

  overflow: auto;
}

.flex-scroll-container {
  display: flex;
}

.break { display: flex; overflow-x: scroll; }

// inner parent allowed to stretch to fit children
.flex-scroll {
   // inside spacing
   padding: 30px 20px;
   
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   //flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.box {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.box:nth-child(3n-2) { background-color: #EF5350; }
.box:nth-child(3n-1) { background-color: #2E7D32; }
.box:nth-child(3n) { background-color: #03A9F4; }
```

I'd like the third row (containing more boxes than the second one) to be the same width of the second row and keep its own horizontal scroll.

Is it possible to achieve?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="flex-scroll-container">
    <div class="flex-scroll">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-scroll-container">
    <div class="flex-scroll">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>

      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>

      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="break">
      <div class="flex-scroll-new">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #aaa;
}

// outer parent to cut a viewing window
#container {
  // center in parent
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  background: #444;

  overflow: auto;
}

.flex-scroll-container {
  display: flex;
}

.break { 
  overflow-x: auto;
}

// inner parent allowed to stretch to fit children
.flex-scroll {
   // inside spacing
   padding: 30px 20px;
   
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   //flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.box {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.break .box {
  min-width: 75px;
}

.flex-scroll-new {
  display: flex;
   padding: 30px 20px;
}

.box:nth-child(3n-2) { background-color: #EF5350; }
.box:nth-child(3n-1) { background-color: #2E7D32; }
.box:nth-child(3n) { background-color: #03A9F4; }
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('.break').style.width = (document.querySelector('.flex-scroll-container:nth-child(2) > .flex-scroll').offsetWidth - 20) + 'px';
```

Comment: width cannot be set on `.break` class... This absolutely does not work... If more boxes are added or removed, everything breaks.

Comment: First, please remove the "flex-scroll-container" class on the break's container div.
And if you want to change the width of break dynamically, please use this javascript code.
document.querySelector('.break').style.width = (document.querySelector('.flex-scroll-container:nth-child(2) > .flex-scroll').offsetWidth - 20) + 'px';

Comment: You are suggesting a JavaScript solution. Totally irrelevant...

Comment: If you want to use only CSS, you can remove all JS and set the height value of .break like this:  .break { height: 690px; overflow-x: auto } But it's static.